# Upload PDF to SalesForce Work Order using JSForce

Tags: javascript, pdf, jsforce

I am trying to use JSForce to upload a PDF file to a WorkOrder in SalesForce.
Here is the code I am trying to use, just don't know how to attach it to a work order ID

```
fs.readFile(pdfPath, function (err, filedata) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        var base64data = new Buffer(filedata).toString('base64');
                        jsForceConn.sobject('Attachment').create({
                            ParentId: wo,
                            Name: pdfName,
                            Body: base64data,
                            ContentType: fileType,
                        },
                            function (err, ret) {
                                if (err || !ret.success) { return console.error(err, ret); }
                                console.log('PDF Uploaded Successfully : ' + ret.id);

                            });
                    }
                });
```

I feel like it is not as simple as setting the `ParentId` to the workorder id

Comment: Does this code not work, and if so, what is the error or issue? What's the value of `wo`?

Comment: @DavidReed It Doesn't give an error, it just doesn't upload anything. the value of `wo` is a work order ID, of the work order that I am trying to upload the PDF attachment to.

It shows that it uploaded successfully and gives an attachment ID, but when I look at the WorkOrder there are no attachments.

Comment: Do you have the classic Attachments related list on your page layout? It's not the same as the Lightning Files related list. If you query in Developer Console for Attachments, do you see it?

Comment: Yeah, it is in as attachments, how do I upload it to Files? instead of Attachments? just change sobject("Attachment") to sobject('File') ?

Comment: So, I added the Notes & Attachments to the View, but it is also empty, I am thinking, it is creating the attachment in SF, but not attaching it.

Comment: I would recommend running some queries in the Developer Console to determine where your Attachment is ending up, and what in fact it is attached to.